# Cannot send mail through phpmailer

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send E-Mails over SMTP using the [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) library I just downloaded from GitHub. I followed a tutorial but it doesn't want to send its E-Mail.

My HTTPD error log returns the following entry:

> [Sun Jul 19 12:44:08.067906 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 12127:tid
>   140673456404224] [client -] AH01071: Got error 'PHP
>   message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: mailtest.php in
>   /home/mick/domains/mcgamerzone.com/public_html/header.php on line
>   56\nPHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SMTP' not found in
>   /home/mick/domains/mcgamerzone.com/public_html/assets/sources/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php
>   on line 1291\n', referer: https://www.mcgamerzone.com/mailtest.php

My code is as follows:

```
require_once("assets/sources/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tsl";
$mail->Host = "mail.mcgamerzone.com";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "do_not_reply@mcgamerzone.com";
$mail->Password = "Pass";
$mail->From = "do_not_reply@mcgamerzone.com";
$mail->FromName = "McGamerZone.com";
$mail->Subject = "Test mail";
$mail->Body = "Testing this awesome mail";
$mail->AddAddress("test@mcgamerzone.com");
if(!$mail->Send()){
    echo "Mailer Error: ". $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message was send.";
}
```

Please help me resolve this issue, thanks.

**Edit: I now get the following output:**

> 2015-07-19 11:05:24 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.mcgamerzone.com
>   2015-07-19 11:05:24 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 2015-07-19 11:05:24
>   SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. 2015-07-19 11:05:24 CLIENT
>   -> SERVER: QUIT 2015-07-19 11:05:25 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: ���~�#������Y�� d�h;�ѵK��
>   u���ZVۯ�<@{���=h�0���Zt��m?�R�j��7����M����U�9Kzշж�"����4��ƺ,��'�j࠹ė���1p��6�(a0�����A]�0'�s��1��s�ՠt�}��
>   Hm��:�D2��1]u���A��͆���������(���!r�.�#���cɵ=�K�
>   )��s�k�u�~�c���qϝ�8Nq�
>   ����O�@2�O-����\���Pl޾{����t�j���㦂JN���ݒ�J��s�wR�}�|b
>   �R�^���j��vi�J��''Z�4���b�RɊ�G"��
>   ��T�t͵�ƲPq|����4���R�E��4Vn0%��0��w�o�[��(����
>   �7�����љc���c�w��j�_/���9��@��Vj���l�������i��r��j��{Zq��L����y��*pe�����+���;b����&A7T�@>x�\��C�W����Iw&L_4b�q�(���A��:/}��\l����$��,�y}�\�?&F��y���=eP�3�Q�&Z�,����k���(̛m~Ç_��S�o
>   �-"����@�����a���r��^&�\23 ���l]J&�^�#n�w�Q�BJ����>��rwG��
>   LÂ�zo۸�G7��e-��d�q cvV$�Sn�o�V��r ��m��k{�D�d��B)\ +��nN��w��%A
>   ?��������b`0s�����0����9��M��� ##�����B���Xi�+C���;3m�q��/>?��n��k���
>   ����T�t��hD�W'>����8��w�ܶԪ(��&ɻ�?8Ȋ�221 mgz05.mgzsys.net closing
>   connection 2015-07-19 11:05:25 SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Any idea why the connection fails? Both the credentials as the host info and encryption type are valid.

Comment: please do not use answer to add more content/code/error, use edit to re-edit your question and update it with updated code.

Comment: That output contains a link, did you read and understand it and how does the info there relate to your case? Also, there's no need to disguise edits as separate paragraphs. In this case it even makes things less clear, because you say "now I get..." without any info what you changed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are doing this:

```
require 'class.phpmailer.class.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

What you should be doing is:

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

The autoloader does not autoload itself, and it's not the PHPMailer class' job to load it.

(source: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/113 )

Comment: I don't get a usefull output, it throws a lot of characters like this: ,��'�j࠹ė���1p��6�(a0�����A]�0'�s��1��s�ՠt�}��

Any advice?